# Convert filtered values from formulas to values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an issue when using the filter, for example, during January. I want to sort the numbers in descending order within this month, but the flash fill feature doesn't work for me because I am using the filter. So, I came up with a for this problem and used:

```
=SUBTOTAL(3,$G$15:G15)
```

As shown in the image,

[image]

now I have another issue: the function only works when I use the filter. I want to convert it to a value only. I tried copy-pasting, but I get an error message.

this action won't work on multiple selections

any solution?

I tried copying and pasting as a value, but it doesn't work for me.

I tried selecting the cells, then pressing F2 and then F9; it works, but only for a single cell.

I want to convert this function into a value.

Comment: Can you post some sample data using https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables and an example of what you'd like to get from the sample. Are you using Office 365, or Excel 2021, or a prior version?

Comment: What column do you want to sort in descending order?  What column is the function in?    I'm wondering if you added the function when the filter was applied or when no filter was applied?  Try doing it when no filter is applied so that you can easily apply it to all cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort your table by Month, then by your function column. Now when you filter the table, all the rows are continuous, and you are allowed to copy and paste as values.

[image]